# datetimepicker is not working in chrome

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

i am using `datetimepicker` in sencha touch but its working in mozila and not working in chrome , have no idea why this is happening.

I have downloaded from sencha market here is the [source](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/datetimepicker/versions/99/download)

mozila ( its working )

[image]

chrome (not working )

[image: not working]

**UPDATE**

simple `datepickerfield` in chrome isnt working so basically there is some bug in sencha touch

try this sample from official sencha touch and open it in chrome

http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/docs/Ext.field.DatePicker.1/

Answer (score 1):

Its because of Chrome v43+, add this code to your controllers init function

```js
if (Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {

        Ext.override(Ext.util.SizeMonitor, {
            constructor: function (config) {
                var namespace = Ext.util.sizemonitor;
                return new namespace.Scroll(config);
            }
        });

        Ext.override(Ext.util.PaintMonitor, {
            constructor: function (config) {
                return new Ext.util.paintmonitor.CssAnimation(config);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the width of any id with css

```
#ext-pickerslot-1{
    width: x%;
}

#ext-pickerslot-2{
   width: y%;
}
```

etc...