# Datepickerfield no value to select : Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sencha-touch-2

In chrome browser , I cannot see any value to select from datepickerfield.
it's working perfectly in FireFox.

I don't have much configuration,

```
               {
                    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                    label: 'Field',
                    placeHolder: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                },
```

see below,

[image]

but it's working in Firefox,

[image]

Any idea what went wrong !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue with Chrome latest version. You can refer these below links -

[datetimepicker is not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314628/datetimepicker-is-not-working-in-chrome)

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301318-datepickerfield-does-not-work-with-latest-Chrome-quot-43.0.2357.65-m-quot

Answer (score 0):

In `app.js` file add below inside `launch()` function:

```
if (Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {

        Ext.override(Ext.util.SizeMonitor, {
            constructor: function (config) {
                var namespace = Ext.util.sizemonitor;
                return new namespace.Scroll(config);
            }
        });

        Ext.override(Ext.util.PaintMonitor, {
            constructor: function (config) {
                return new Ext.util.paintmonitor.CssAnimation(config);
            }
        });
 }
```

It will work like charm again. It is issue with Chrome 43+ version.